# Irregularly shaped UIBezierPath filling

Tags: iphone, ios, quartz-graphics, cgpath, uibezierpath

I'm making some custom control. One of the subviews of the control is transparent `UIView` with `UIBezierPath` path drawn on. On the one of the photos there is just let's say border of the `UIBezierPath` (there's called [path stroke]), but on the second one you can see what happens when I call [path fill]. I'd like the path filled to create shape similar to the one on the first photo. `drawRect` method from this transparent `UIView` is below.

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
[super drawRect:rect];
UIBezierPath *path;
[[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
[[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
//Angles

CGFloat startAngle = degreesToRadians(225);
CGFloat endAngle = degreesToRadians(315);

CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), lRadius);
path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter: center radius:lRadius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
rightEndOfLine = path.currentPoint;
bigArcHeight = rightEndOfLine.y;


CGFloat smallArcHeight = lRadius - bigArcHeight - sRadius;
CGFloat smallArcWidthSquare = (8*smallArcHeight*sRadius) - (4 * (smallArcHeight * smallArcHeight));
smallArcWidth = sqrtf(smallArcWidthSquare);


leftStartOfLine = CGPointMake((rect.size.width - smallArcWidth)/2, lRadius-sRadius + smallArcHeight);    
CGFloat lengthOfSpace = (rect.size.width - rightEndOfLine.x);

[path moveToPoint:leftStartOfLine];
[path addArcWithCenter:center radius:sRadius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
rightStartOfLine = path.currentPoint;
leftEndOfLine = CGPointMake(lengthOfSpace, bigArcHeight);
[path moveToPoint:rightStartOfLine];
[path addLineToPoint:rightEndOfLine];
[path moveToPoint:leftStartOfLine];
[path addLineToPoint:leftEndOfLine];
[path closePath];
[path stroke];
 // [path fill];

 }
```

Thanks for help !

[image: First Image] 
[image: Second Image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove all of your moveToPoint calls. This is a continuous shape so they are not required, and they are confusing the filling algorithm. You can start at the top left corner, draw the arc clockwise, draw the segment (?) line, draw the arc anticlockwise, then draw the last segment line (or close the path). This will fill properly.